# Sharing same rules for Stylecop and Fxcop across Build server and Developer Machine

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, jenkins, tfs

We are trying to setup continuous integration process. As part of this we have setup Jenkins on build server . Plugins are added to Jenkins in order to check and validate StyleCop and Fxcop rules.

We are multiple teams working from different locations. As we are implementing Stylecop and Fxcop in Development process , We would like to share one single copy of Stylecop setting and Fxcop ruleset across developers  and also we want to use the same rules in Jenkins plugins Build Machine .

Below I have added a image on what we are looking at . As below each developer will be directly accessing the settings file in Build Machine.It's Seems difficult ,but if there is a way surely we would like to implement the same. [image]

We are using GIT, TFS , Jenkins and Visual Studio 2013 .  Please let me know your comments on this

Answer (score 1):

We store our StyleCop.Settings file in TFS at the team project root/solution root.  So you might still have duplication across team projects but we mainly work out of two team projects at our company so it's not that big of a deal.

We also store the StyleCop binaries in TFS such that each developer doesn't need to install StyleCop and it also doesn't have to be installed on the build server that way. We'll include it in the csproj file like this

`<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\Tools\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />`

So our tfs structure might look like this:

TeamProject/
----Dev/
----Main/
--------Solution1.sln
--------Solution2.sln
--------StyleCop.settings
--------Tools/
------------StyleCop/
----Release/